# Qt5 and MacOS X

Tags: qt, osx-yosemite

I've installed Qt5 on my Mac OS X Yosemite from MacPorts.
If I compile this simple file

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel lbl("Hello World!");
    lbl.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I'll get error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QApplication::exec()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "QApplication::~QApplication()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "QLabel::QLabel(QString const&, QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "QLabel::~QLabel()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "QWidget::show()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [123.app/Contents/MacOS/123] Error 1
```

I've change `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6`
to `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.9` 
or `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.10`
in file /opt/local/share/qt5/mkspecs/macx-clang/qmake.conf
but it has no result.

Comment: Did you install 64bit qt? (is it possible not to?)

Comment: I've installed by "sudo port install qt5-mac". I suppose, it is 64bit.

Comment: Can you show the linker command?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know exactly without more information, but check that you are adding in widgets in your .pro file:

```
QT       += gui core
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

You may have to run qmake explicitly if you aren't using qtcreator. Also, wouldn't you be showing a main window instead of a QLabel? I haven't checked if that's legit doable code, but maybe you should start showing a main window and verify that works first. QTCreator has a project template for a new  `Qt Widgets Application`. Also check to see that macports is installing the latest qt5 version in the event it's a bad path or config on their part.